# DidUpdateLocation unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I'm new in iOS development and I'm currently facing a problem I don't know the answer for. I've been struggling with it for a while now, so I hope I can get some help here.

The problem persists while using the LocationManager class. I made a singleton which should be accessible from every class. This seems to work, but for some reason I'm getting a 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' in my DidUpdateLoation delegate. Could someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Error:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyPFQueryTableViewController locationControllerDidUpdateLocation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x805e8c0'**

**LocationController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@protocol SCLocationControllerDelegate

- (void)locationControllerDidUpdateLocation:(CLLocation *)location;

@end

@interface SCLocationController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocation *location;

@property (weak, nonatomic) id delegate;

+ (SCLocationController *)sharedController;

@end
```

**LocationController.m**

```
#import "LocationController.h"

@interface SCLocationController ()

@end

@implementation SCLocationController

+ (SCLocationController *)sharedController
{
    static SCLocationController *sharedController = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedController = [[self alloc]init];
    });

    return sharedController;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
        _locationManager.delegate = self;
        _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        _locationManager.distanceFilter = 30; // Meters.
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Location Manager

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    [self.delegate locationControllerDidUpdateLocation:locations.lastObject];
    [self setLocation:locations.lastObject];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // ...
}

@end
```

**Usage:**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[SCLocationController sharedController]setDelegate:self];
    [[SCLocationController sharedController].locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: We could tell you if you would post the actual error message instead of paraphrasing it.

Comment: @rdelmar sorry, updated my post.

Comment: Do you have a locationControllerDidUpdateLocation: method in your MyPFQueryTableViewController?

Comment: @rdelmar No I don't.. When I remove this line from the didUpdateLocations: [self setLocation:locations.lastObject];

It doesn't crash anymore, but I'm getting location 0.0000 when using simulator and following code to get latest location:     NSLog(@"%.8f",[[SCLocationController sharedController] locationManager].location.coordinate.latitude);

Comment: Well, then that's you problem. Did you mean to call locationControllerDidUpdateLocation: on some other object? You're calling it on your delegate, which is apparently a MyPFQueryTableViewController instance.

Comment: Alright, seems obvious to be honest. but am I also missing a setLocation method? Since it crashes on this.. 

Last question by the way: If I implement the locationControllerDidUpdateLocation method.. it requires an object (lastObject) how am I sure what kind of type object this is? Because I can't figure out the method signature

Comment: @rdelmar nevermind got it, CCLocation object (obvious) :/ thanks for your help.. Trying to implement it now!

Comment: @rdelmar Post your answer so I can accept